# Xamarin Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException:

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I have a problem whit deserialize Json Object:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[xxx.Models.FollowerResponseModel]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'users', line 2, position 10.

```
{"result":{"status":200,"response":{"data":{"users":[
{"uin":223,"login":"tttttt","uin_follows":true,"follow_of_uin":false,"blocked":false},
{"uin":225,"login":"hggjhjj","uin_follows":false,"follow_of_uin":true,"blocked":true},
{"uin":226,"login":"testestefy","uin_follows":false,"follow_of_uin":false,"blocked":true}
],"version":"1"}}}}
```

My FollowersResponModel

```
public class FollowerResponseModel
{
    [JsonProperty("users")]
    public List<UserFollowersModel> Users { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("version")]
    public int Version { get; set; }
}

public class UserFollowersModel
{
    [JsonProperty("uin")]
    public int Uin { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("login")]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("uin_follows")]
    public bool UinFollows { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("follow_of_uin")]
    public bool FollowOfUin { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("blocked")]
    public bool Blocked { get; set; }
}
```

How should my FollowersModel class look like?

My method GetFollowers...

```
public async Task<List<FollowerModel>> GetFollowersBlockedList(int version)
{
    var request = CreateHttpRequest(string.Format(FOLLOWERS_BLOCKED_URL), HttpMethod.Get, true);

    var response = await CallRequestAsync(request, HttpContentType.ApplicationJson);

    if (response == null) return null;

    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    var content = Tools.ConvertStreamToString(stream);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content)) return null;

    var responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(content);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        _log.MessageInDebug("OK");

        var data = responseModel.Result.Response.Data.ToString();

        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FollowerResponseModel>>(data);

        if (list == null || list.Count() == 0) return null;

        return list.Select(x => new FollowerModel(x)).ToList();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: What does the json look like on the response? Make sure users is an array.

Comment: what does the json look like?  You are trying to deserialize into a List<FollowerResponseModel>, but it is telling you the json is a single object

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add :
{"result":{"status":200,"response":{"data":{"users":[
{"uin":223,"login":"tttttt","uin_follows":true,"follow_of_uin":false,"blocked":false},
{"uin":225,"login":"hggjhjj","uin_follows":false,"follow_of_uin":true,"blocked":true},
{"uin":226,"login":"testestefy","uin_follows":false,"follow_of_uin":false,"blocked":true}
],"version":"1"}}}}

Comment: You are trying to deserialize data, which is an object.  Data["users"] is an array.

Comment: @Jason Please can you show me how it should look like ?

Comment: Take your json und past it to json2csharp.com. This will generate the classes you need.

Comment: I have class:
   public class ResponseModel
    {
        public class ResponseC
        {
            [JsonProperty("message")]
            public string Message { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("data")]
            public object Data { get; set; }
        }

        public class ResultC
        {
            [JsonProperty("status")]
            public int Status { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("response")]
            public ResponseC Response { get; set; }
        }

        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public ResultC Result { get; set; }
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FollowerResponseModel` already contains a `List<User>`, so you do not need to deserialize a `List<FollowerResponseModel>`

```
var follow = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FollowerResponseModel>(data);

if (follow.Users == null || follow.Users.Count() == 0) return null;
```